# Swift Scenekit - Multiple rotations

Tags: swift, rotation, scenekit

I have an issue with rotating an a node multiple times. I am working on a game with a rolling ball, and while I can rotate the ball along one axis, or two axis by the same amount, I cannot rotate at partial angles.

example:

```
// Roll right  90 - 
SCNNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(Float(M_PI_2), 0, 1, 0)

// Roll right 180 - 
SCNNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(Float(M_PI_2) * 2, 0, 1, 0)

// Roll up     90 - 
SCNNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(Float(M_PI_2), 1, 0, 0)

// Roll up & right 90 - 
SCNNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(Float(M_PI_2), 1, 1, 0)
```

All of which will work, however if I need to roll ball right 180 and up 90 I'm stuck.

Even if there was some way to add the vectors together that would do me.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To combine the effects of [rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix), use matrix multiplication.

To do that in SceneKit, you can either:

- Create separate rotation matrices and multiply them together using [`SCNMatrix4Mult`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/1409697-scnmatrix4mult).
- Apply a rotation directly to an existing matrix using [`SCNMatrix4Rotate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/1409659-scnmatrix4rotate). (This is equivalent to the `SCNMatrix4MakeRotation` + `SCNMatrix4Mult` option; it just combines those steps into a single function call.)

If the order of transformations is important to your app, remember that [matrix multiplication order is the reverse of transformation order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Composing_and_inverting_transformations).

Comment: One thing that I did find that's worth noting, and this may be well known to everyone else, but I didn't realise at first. Before you rotate it, the axis of the node, matches the access of the parent node. Once the node has been rotated, a second rotation is done relative to its new axis, not to the original/parent node axis. Seems logical enough now I know, but still adjusting to three dimensional thinking. Thanks for the help rickster.